# Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1312

I have created a stored procedure in Mysql, as :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM buyers;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

but when i call it using,

```
call test()
```

it returns an error saying :

> #1312 - PROCEDURE ticketninja.test1 can't return a result set in the given context

Answer (score 2):

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

> Statements that return a result set can be used within a stored procedcure but not within a stored function. This prohibition includes SELECT statements that do not have an INTO var_list clause and other statements such as SHOW, EXPLAIN, and CHECK TABLE. For statements that can be determined at function definition time to return a result set, a Not allowed to return a result set from a function error occurs (ER_SP_NO_RETSET). For statements that can be determined only at runtime to return a result set, a PROCEDURE %s can't return a result set in the given context error occurs (ER_SP_BADSELECT).

Maybe you need to utilize a temporary table, like in this example:

- http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/mysql-stored-procedures.html

Comment: it is giving an error :
#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: updated my post; the linked resource contains a full example which you might be able to adjust.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your code (or client library) calls `mysql_set_server_options()` with `MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON` enabled.